# Parallels does not trigger Turbo Boost on a Mac Book Pro

Tags: mac, performance, intel-core-i7, parallels, turbo-boost

I've asked this question on PD forum but I think there are more audiences here... Here the question comes :)

I tried a simple google search and comes out nothing so I guess few have noticed about this potential issue that may make our VM perform slower than it could be.

On modern Intel CPUs, there's a built-in technology Turbo Boost which turns the clock speed up while we're on some heavy work and returns to a low frequency when the work is done or the CPU is going to overheat due to bad cooling(or work on a higher clock speed for too long).

Before I go into more detail, I'm testing(using) an MBP 2017 with this CPU `3.1GHz quad-core Intel Core i7, Turbo Boost up to 4.1GHz, with 8MB shared L3 cache`

When I'm using a Mac application, the turbo boost is always working. If I build a project in Android Studio, the CPU frequency goes up to 3.8GHz in my observation(don't know if it actually goes up to 4.1GHz, doesn't matter since it is at least boosted).

However, when I'm on PD Win VM, even if I build a big project in VS which consumes almost all CPU on the VM and consumes around 50-60% of CPU on the Mac(I allocate 4 logic cores to VM which is the recommended setting), Turbo boost is not triggered, CPU is running constantly in a frequency of 2.2-2.5 GHz, rarely goes to 3GHz.

I know this could be a difficult issue to solve as it involves a hardware technology(maybe Mac's CPU management as well) but if our VM can trigger Turbo Boost, our peak(period) performance can be boosted ~50%(the calculation is (3.8-2.5)/2.5).

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virtual CPU, that Parallels presents to the VM need not have (and most often will not have) all features, that the physical CPU of the host has. Turbo boost is one feature, that suffers quite often: In oder to make good use of it, the System must have a bird's eye view on what's happening on all cores of the CPU - a VM obviously doesn't have that.

More generally: Whatever goes on in the CPU thermal management can not easily be done by a VM, but only by the host OS, as a VM lacks the knowledge to manage it.

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer. I don't have knowledge on how the VM uses the CPU, isn't it managed by the host(virtualization software), or is it just directly uses the CPU cores allocated to the VM and host loses control over those cores? I don't get why CPU does not trigger turbo while it knows that there's something heavy going on(based on cpu usage?), no matter the heavy load is caused by host app or a VM app.

Comment: CPU thermal management (which is where Turbo Boost is housed) needs cooperation between the OS and the CPU. If the OS doesn't cooperate, the CPU will run "safe" (i.e. without Turbo Boost). The OS in the VM can't cooperate with the CPU, as it lacks the knowledge to, so it can't request the CPU to speed up.

Comment: Okay.. I think the lack of proficient knowledge in this area makes me unable to understand why vm os can’t get those info. Anyway thanks for the explanation, have marked as accepted.